# CompletableFuture, run asynchronous code after "join"

Tags: java, asynchronous

I'm facing some trouble after some month only on Javascript/Typescript.

For example, let see this snippet:

```
@Test
    public void testAsync(){
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->{
            try{
                Thread.sleep(10000);
                System.out.println("After some seconds");
            }catch(InterruptedException exc){
                return "Fail";
            }
            return "Done";
        }).thenAccept(s->System.out.println(s)).join();

        System.out.println("should write before After some seconds statement");
    }
```

I was expecting the last system.out.println to run before the CompletableFuture but it await the complete of the Future.

So, what I got is:
"After some seconds"
"Done"
"should write before After some seconds statement"

What I want:
"should write before After some seconds statement"
"After some seconds"
"Done"

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Remove the `join()`? Or move it after the print?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the future in a variable, print the statement, then `join()` to wait for the result:

```
CompletableFuture<Void> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        System.out.println("After some seconds");
    } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
        return "Fail";
    }
    return "Done";
}).thenAccept(s -> System.out.println(s));
System.out.println("should write before After some seconds statement");
future.join();
```

As for the explanation, the javadoc of the `.join()` method says:

> Returns the result value when complete, or throws an (unchecked) exception if completed exceptionally

That means, if you call `.join()` chained to `thenAccept()`, it means that you will first wait for the `supplyAsync()` to end, then will `thenAccept()`, and will wait for such result via the `join()`.

Hence, you will reach your `System.out.println("should write before After some seconds statement");` just after all operations are completed.

If your objective was to wait for the future before completing the test, then you should call the `join()` after printing with the main thread, not before.